# Passport.JS doesn't work (AngularJS + NodeJS + MySQL + Redis Store for session datas)

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js, node-mysql, node-redis

I'm trying to use PassportJS to authenticate requests on my site, but it's not working. When I trying to login nothing happening. I'm using MYSQL database to store the user datas and I didn't find a tutorial for this.

APP.JS:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var routes = require('./routes');
var sha1 = require('sha1');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 6379,
        prefix: 'sess'
    }),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'xxxxxxx'
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },

    function(username, password, done){

        var connection = mysql.createConnection(
            {
              host     : sql.host,
              user     : sql.user,
              password : sql.password,
              database : sql.db_users
            }

        );

        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);

        connection.connect();

        var queryUserCheck = 'SELECT userID, email, password, users WHERE email = "' + username + '"';

        connection.query(queryUserCheck, function(err, rows, field) {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).end(err);
                console.log(err);
                connection.end();

            }else{

                user = rows[0];
                userID = rows[0].userID;
                console.log('Checkpoint 1');

                if(!user) { return done(null, false, {message: 'The user is not exist'});}
                else if(sha1(password) != user.password) { return done(null, false, {message: "Wrong password"});}
                else{
                    console.log('Checkpoint 2'); 
                    return done(null, user);}
                connection.end();
            }
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser');
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
    });
});

routes.init(app, passport);
```

I'm actually not really understand the above 2 function. I know it's need to attach and deattach the user from the session, but do I need to change anything on these functions to make it customized or just leave as is?

Router:

```
exports.init = function(app, passport){

app.post('/login', login);
app.get('/logout', logout);
app.get('/userinfo', checkAuth, require('./users/users/userDetails'));


function login(req, res, next){

passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){
        return next(err);
    }

    console.log('Authentication is successfull');

});
}

function logout(req, res){

if(req.isAuthenticated()){

    req.logout();
    req.session.messages = "Log out successfully";

}

 res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
 res.end(true);

}

 function checkAuth(req, res, next){

   if(req.isAuthenticated) return next();
   else{
   res.status(401).end("Not Authorized!");
 }
}

};
```

Could somebody help me what I missed? Thank you so much.